# Relaciones en SQL

Tags: sql, uml

hace poco tuve una duda con mi profesora en bases de datos que no pudo resolver, quisiera preguntar cual es la mejor forma o cual es la forma adecuada para resolver este problema.

Como pueden ver en la foto tengo las tablas `Clientes` y `Habitacion` relacionadas pero lo que no entiendo es por que al relacionarlas de forma viceversa se me crean mas relaciones en las tablas siguiente. Así es como sql detecta las relaciones o el programa las crea como parte de su sistema.

Cual es la mejor forma de relacionar? `Clientes` a `Habitaciones` o viceversa?

Perdonen no ser tan especifico, déjenme comentarios para aclarar. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que lo ideal sería ver el enunciado de tu problema para poder tener mas contexto, pero al margen de eso la relación sería de uno a uno donde una habitación es o le pertenece solo a un cliente

Comment: @ShadowPaz gracias por comentar, no es necesario colocar el texto, es largo, era un ejemplo, pero lo que quiero saber es si todas las relaciones al final se ven representadas como aparece en la segunda imagen, como puedes ver es mucho. Te dejo el link para que veas como funciona https://sqldbm.com/Project/SQLServer/Share/EU9Lwf_BXIgZ-Y233pO-Rw

Comment: personalmente la considero correcta ya que no solo abarca hacer el registro si no que también verifica para sus registros el tipo de habitación y costo, repito a título personal la veo correcta

Comment: la segunda, espero ser de utilidad con mi opinión

Comment: @ShadowPaz gracias